# microprogram assembler (jasmin)

Tags: assembly, nasm, jasmin-x86

what does this command do in assambly ?

```
mov ebx, [eax+ecx*4+12]
```

does it do the same of the following ?

```
MOV EBX,ECX
ADD EBX,EBX ; *2
ADD EBX,EBX ; *4
ADD EBX,EAX
ADD EBX,12
MOV EBX,[EBX]
```

if yes why do they don't give the same result in ***Jasmin*** when `eax = 100h`, `ebx = 0`, `ecx = 100h`

end.

Comment: This seems unrelated to Jasmin, the JVM assembler, because `mov` and `add` are not the proper mnemonics for any instruction for JVM.

Comment: @Tinctorius: I believe the question is referring to [this Jasmin](http://www.lrr.in.tum.de/~jasmin/), not [the other one](http://jasmin.sourceforge.net/).  I wonder if it should have a separate tag.  Maybe [tag:jasmin-x86]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lets say we have these commands

```
mov eax, 0x1234 ; 1234h
mov ebx, 0
mov ecx, 0x1234 ; 1234h
MOV EBX,ECX ; ebx = 0x1234
ADD EBX,EBX ; *2
ADD EBX,EBX ; *4
ADD EBX,EAX ; ebx = 0x5B04
ADD EBX,12  ; ebx = 0x5B10
MOV EBX, [EBX] ; Error out of range

; Or
mov ebx, [eax+ecx*4+12] ; => mov ebx, [0x1234+0x1234*4+12]
```

=> its actually ***mov ebx, [0x5B10]*** where ***0x5B10*** is the address number in the memory, but in my case the maximal address is ***0xFFC < 0x5B10***, so its out of range so the appeared result is the result of the before last command

so by using smaller values like **0x14** we get the same result

```
mov eax, 0x14 ; eax = 0x14
mov ebx, 0    ; ebx = 0
mov ecx, 0x14 ; ecx = 0x14
MOV EBX,ECX   ; ebx = 0x14
ADD EBX,EBX   ; *2
ADD EBX,EBX   ; *4
ADD EBX,EAX   ; ebx = 0x64
ADD EBX,12    ; ebx = 0x70
MOV EBX, [EBX] ; => mov ebx, [0x70]

; Or
mov ebx, [eax+ecx*4+12] ; => mov ebx, [0x14+0x14*4+12] => mov ebx, [0x70]
```

we get in both cases or methode:

```
eax = 0x14
ebx = 0   => its 0 because the address 0x70 in the memory is empty = 0x0000
ecx = 0x14
```

**BUT** if we add before the last line something like

```
mov [0x70], 0x111
```

we will get in ***ebx 0x111***